# T-SQL SP Dynamic Delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to write SP to delete rows from given table based on ID column. I tried the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.delResTab @schema VARCHAR(20), @table VARCHAR(50), @tableID int

AS

    DECLARE @column VARCHAR(50) = (
                              SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
                              WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
                              AND TABLE_NAME = @table
                              AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 1
                            )

    DELETE FROM @schema + '.' + @table WHERE @column >= @tableId
```

but this does not work obviously. Any advice?

I want to be able to run

```
exec dbo.delResTab @schema = 'dbo', @table = 'test', @tableID = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.delResTab
(
    @schema SYSNAME,
    @table SYSNAME,
    @tableID INT
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = '
        DELETE FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + ']
        WHERE ' + c.name + ' >= ' + CAST(@tableID AS NVARCHAR(10))
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.is_identity = 1
        AND c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@schema + '.' + @table)

    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Comment: That's it. Will accept as soon as I am able too. Thanks.